# Trying to run a backup on another Jenkins server

Tags: jenkins, server, jenkins-plugins, hudson

I recently had some issues regarding version upgrade for my Jenkins server. In order to update the version of the jenkins server, the first step I did was to create a backup:

```
sudo tar -zcvf /tmp/jenkins.tgz /var/lib/jenkins
```

Then, I copied the archived file, from server A and untar it on another server, server B. I can see all the files [workspace, config.xml, jobs] of server A to server B in `var/lib/jenkins`.

When I am logging into the jenkins box it showed:

```
Jenkins detected that you appear to be running more than one instance of Jenkins that share the same home directory '/var/lib/jenkins’. This greatly confuses Jenkins and you will likely experience strange behaviors, so please correct the situation.
This Jenkins:
490566619 contextPath="" at 8779@jm1597185631ybr.cloud.phx3.gdg
Other Jenkins:
1998724099 contextPath="" at 20292@jm1584048540yxl.cloud.phx3.gdg
```

So, I stopped the jenkins service using:

```
sudo service jenkins stop
```

Then I restarted the service using

```
sudo service jenkins restart
```

All the jobs started to appear suddenly. I have following questions:
Why did the jobs started to show up and not throw the error of running multiple instances?

1. If version is the only issue, why cannot the newly provisioned
   server have the updated version? Is it when I copy the files from server A, the server B files gets overwritten and hence, shows the same error of the version upgrade?

Comment: Did you stop the instances before tar'ng and untar'ng? Did you happen to tar the running pidfile? Did you wipe the target instance before untar'ng?

Comment: If you mean stop the jenkins server, No. I didn't take down the servers but there were no jobs running. When I stopped the jenkins service of the server B [new one] and restarted, it seemed to work for some reason.